# Magento: Get all fields of an order?

Tags: magento-1.9

how can i get all fields of an order in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Order General Info:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
zend_debug::dump($order->getData());
```

For Order Billing Address:

```
zend_debug::dump($order->getBillingAddress());
```

For Order Shipping Address:

```
zend_debug::dump($order->getShippingAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the data of an order as an array then loop through it:

```
$data = $order->getData();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    //so something with $key or $value
}
```